# I am installing `npm install` but it give me error : Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I want to install `npm install` but it give me error. Could you please help me what problem I may face . I am beginner and did't point out what the exact problem?

```
c:\users\user\.node-gyp\11.3.0\include\node\v8.h(10248): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToString'
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\blonk-backoffice\node_modules\bcrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v11.3.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-09T14_32_12
```

_077Z-debug.log

Comment: what are you trying to `npm install` and what version of node/npm are you runinng? `node -v` and `npm -v` respectively.

Comment: Can you confirm, that you installed node-gyp and it's dev dependencies correctly according to [the windows installation guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)?